# Does it make sense to write integration/end-to-end tests for api-gateway?

Tags: java, spring, aws-api-gateway, integration-testing, api-gateway

just want to know/see different point of views regarding this type of tests for api-gateway and your experience if you had something similar in your practice.
Thank you.

Comment: Because a gateway is involved?  No.  But a gateway is just part of the implementation.  Is the focus on testing the behavior or the implementation?

Comment: untest for  gateway is uncessary , pay more attendion to major logic .

Comment: Not a bad idea, especially if you have special configurations applied.  A quick test will ensure that breaking changes haven't been made.  However, I generally do not.

Comment: You may want to consider doing contract testing on your APIs just to ensure that they are not broken after any change promotion. I don't recommend doing full E2E testing though. I have used Pact framework in one of my project earlier for contract testing. https://docs.pact.io/